# CUDA and Monte Carlo with local behavior defined

Tags: cuda, montecarlo

I have a question about a strange behavior In CUDA. 
I am currently developing a Monte Carlo simulation on particles trajectories and I am doing the following the thing.

The position p(n) of my particle at a given date t(n) depends on the position t(n-1) of my particle at the previous date t(n-1). Indeed, let’s say the value v(n) is computed from the value p(n-1).  Here is a simplified example of my code:

```
__device__ inline double calculateStep( double drift, double vol, double dt, double randomWalk, double S_t){
  return exp((drift - vol*vol*0.5)*dt + randomWalk*vol*sqrt(dt))*S_t;
}    

__device__ double doSomethingWhith(double v_n, ….) {
  ...
  Return v_n*exp(t)*S
}



__global__ myMCsimulation( double* matrice, double * randomWalk, int nbreSimulation, int nPaths, double drift, ……) {


  double dt = T/nPaths;
  unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x; 
  unsigned int stride = blockDim.x*gridDim.x;
  unsigned int index = tid;  
  double mydt = (index - nbreSimulation)/nbreSimulation*dt + dt;

  for ( index = tid; index < nbreSimulation*nPaths; index += stride) {
    if (index >= nbreSimulation)
    {
     double v_n = DoSomethingWith(drift,dt, matrice[index – nbreSimulation]);
     matrice[index] = matrice[index - nbreSimulation ] * calculateStep(drift,v_n,dt,randomWalk[index]); // 
    }
...}
```

The last code line :

```
matrice[index] = matrice[index - nbreSimulation ] * calculateStep(drift,v_n,dt,randomWalk[index]);
```

enables me to fill in only the second row of the matrix matrice. I don’t know why.

When I change the code line by :

```
matrice[index] =  DoSomethingWith(drift,dt, matrice[index – nbreSimulation]);
```

My matrix is well filled in and I have all my values changed, then I am able to get back the `matrice[index – nbreSimulation]`.
I think this is a concurrent access but I am not sure, I tried `__syncthreads()` but it did not work.

Could someone please help on this point?

Many thanks

Comment: Regardless of this question, I would suggest that you start accepting the answers that were helpful to you. See the [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page.

Comment: It looks like there might be a concurrent access issue with `matrice[index] = matrice[index - nbreSimulation] * ...` if there is a thread that corresponds to `index - nbreSimulation` -- that thread might run before or after the thread that corresponds to `index`. But I don't think that would explain only some values in the matrix getting filled.  It may just be an indexing issue on the matrix.  Have you tried running the code with `cuda-memcheck` ?  It may show some out-of-bounds indexing that might give a clue. I'm not aware of a `__synchronize()` call, perhaps you meant `__syncthreads()` ?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes I made a mistake, it is __syncthreads(). In my code, a particle path is simulated by one thread, then normally it should be ok regarding the concurrent access. I cannot explain this strange behavior. The multiplication triggers a strange result..

Comment: are you doing cuda error checking on all your kernel calls and cuda calls?  have you run your code through cuda-memcheck?  I guess this isn't actually the code you're using anyway, since you define `double dt` after using it.

Comment: You are right. This is just a sample. I am sorry for this error. I have just simplified my code.

Comment: what happens when you run the code with cuda-memcheck?

Comment: I am using Matlab & the GPU toolkit to run my code (with feval), I dont know if this is possible to use cuda-memcheck... i am investigating on this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed my code by the following thing and now it works perfectly.

```
if (index < nbreSimulation) {
            matrice[index] = S0;    
            for (workingCol=1; workingCol< nPaths; workingCol++) {
                previousMove = index; 
                index = index + nbreSimulation;
                  ................
                matrice[index] = calculateStep(drift,vol_int[index],dt,randomWalk[index], matrice[previousMove]);             }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following thing :

I have declared a shared variable (an array of doubles) which contains the value computed at each iteration :

```
__shared__ double mat[];

......
for ( index = tid; index < nbreSimulation*nPaths; index += stride) {
   .....
  mat[index] = computedValue;
   ......
 }
```

Without success. Does anyone see the issue?